# Optimal way to compare elements of 2D arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have two 2D arrays, each one representing tiles of square areas, and I want to compare each element of the first with each element of the second one. Apart from a straightforward quadruple for-loop, is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
for (int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
  for (int j=0; j<array1[0].length; j++){
    for (int k=0; k<array2.length; k++){
      for (int l=0; l<array2[0].length; l++){
        if (array1[i][j] == array2[k][l]){
          // do something
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly don't believe so, you could however code a method to do this to make it look more organized and elegant.

[A duplicate of your question BTW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555784/compare-elements-of-rows-or-columns-in-2d-array-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Arrays.deepEquals(array1, array2);
```

Comment: Maybe my phrasing was not correct. I want to compare each element, i.e. for each element of the first array, find which element of the second array is equal to it. But thanks anyway, I didn't know about deepEquals, it's good to know :)